# ¿Cómo obtengo los valores de un date picker en Android?

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Tengo este código en le main activity:

```
public void mostrar(View view){
    DatePicker dtp_fecha;
    TextView txvfecha_hora;
    int dia,mes,ano;
    dtp_fecha=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dtp_fecha);
    txvfecha_hora=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvfecha_hora);
    dia=dtp_fecha.getDayOfMonth();
    mes=dtp_fecha.getMonth()+1;
    ano=dtp_fecha.getYear();
    txvfecha_hora.setText(dia);
}
```

No me funciona, lo corro y se me crashea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primera **mostrar** es un botón? dentro del mismo layout del DatePicker?

Deberías hacer algo así:

```
public void mostrar(View view){
 DialogFragment newFragment=new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
}
```

Y en tu datepicker class o si inflas un view podría ser mejor ya controlas todo.

```
 public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int  day) {
            String years=""+year;
            String months=""+(monthOfYear+1);
            String days=""+day;
            if(monthOfYear>=0 && monthOfYear<9){
                months="0"+(monthOfYear+1);
            }
            if(day>0 && day<10){
                days="0"+day;

            }
            txvfecha_hora.setText(days+"/"+months+"/"+years);


        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=null;
            datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

            return datePickerDialog;
        }

    }
```

Pregunta sin problema si te quedan dudas :)

Estos links pueden ayudarte :)

[Android date picker example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/)

[Android Date Picker Tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-date-picker-tutorial/)